# bulletproof URL matching regex for javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Can anyone help me find a regex pattern that will match any and all URL patterns, i've found a couple but they seem to be flawed.

Im not really interested in matching any of the individual elements inside the URLs (such as domain or whatnot), I just need to extract a URL in its entirety from a text string reliably and then output a usable URL (meaning it should always have an http:// in front)

Here are example urls that I would like to match

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
code.google.com
http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aPython
```

Notive that some are missing the http:// tags, so I'd like to then have those added in if they are missing

Final result of function should be

```
1: http://www.google.com
2: http://www.google.com
3: http://code.google.com
4: http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aPython
```

Comment: What will you do with the returned URL? You will have to use a loose regex to accomodate your examples but the confidence could be strengthened by using ajax against the approximated URL to verify whether or not it is valid

Comment: I am actually going to wrap the result in BBCODE, i.e. [url]http://www.google.com[/url]

Comment: str.match(/(http:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.){1,}[a-zA-Z0-9\?%=_\-\+\/]*/g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
<script>
var html = 'http://www.google.com';
html += '\rwww.google.com ';
html += '\rcode.google.com';
html += '\rhttp://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aPython';
var regex = /(https?:\/\/)?(\w+\.?)+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\?%=_\-\+\/]+)?/gi;
alert('before replace:');
alert(html);
html = html.replace(regex, function (match, capture) {
    if (capture) {
        return match
    }
    else {
        return 'http://' + match;
    }
});
alert('after replace:');
alert(html);
</script>
```